# Package "ps-watcher" behaves differently on Bookworm

Tags: debian

One of my Raspberry Pis, a **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3 (4 Cores)**, was running on Raspberry Pi OS 11 (bullseye). I successfully installed Raspberry Pi OS 12 (bookworm) and everything is running perfectly.

One of my projects makes use of package "*ps-watcher*" to display running processes on a dashboard.

On **Bullseye**, the following command:

```
$ ps -e k-pcpu -o pcpu,args | head -n 5
```

Would return the following output:

```
%CPU COMMAND
 4.8 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
 3.1 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
 2.3 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
 1.4 lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
```

When I run the same command on **Bookworm**, this is the returned output:

```
%CPU COMMAND
 200 ps -e k-pcpu -o pcpu,args
 2.4 lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
 0.2 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
 0.2 /lib/systemd/systemd-hostnamed
```

The second line is returning the command executed with a value of 200 as `%CPU`.

I have tried the following variations with no success:

Command:

```
$ ps xo pcpu,comm --sort -pcpu | head -n 5
```

Result:

```
%CPU COMMAND
 500 ps
 2.4 lxpanel
 0.3 bash
 0.0 sshd
```

Command:

```
$ ps -do pcpu,comm --sort -pcpu | head -n 5
```

Result:

```
%CPU COMMAND
 400 ps
 2.4 lxpanel
 0.0 sshd
 0.0 kworker/u9:0-brcmf_wq/mmc1:0001:1
```

Command:

```
$ ps xo -d pcpu,comm --sort -pcpu | head -n 5
```

Result:

```
error: process ID list syntax error
```

How do I modify the command to return the original result?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my Pi (3 Model B Rev 1.2, FWIW) running Bookworm - I get expected output more typical of your Bullseye. `dpkg -l procps` → `2:3.3.17-5`

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response, @ChrisDavies. I will keep investigating and report back if I solve it. Thanks again.